# Laravel Echo not receiving notification from pusher

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.4, pusher

I followed up some tutorials about echo and pusher. I configured all the project as necessary but object notifications not appear at browser. I uncoment the line

> App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,

I created and registered a component in vuejs called notifications then I set it out what says in [laravel notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications) .

```
mounted(){
        window.Echo.private('App.User.1')
            .notification( (notification) => {
                console.log('test'); //====> Never logs
                console.log(notification); //====> Never logs
            });
    },
```

Everything is connecting with Pusher but when I send any notification it appear at pusher, the object notification is not appearing.

[image: view]

Someone have some idea about what is happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not add images for code it's difficult to help you by anyone here

Comment: seems like an echo issue https://github.com/laravel/echo/issues/135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why the .notify is not working, but for while I changed for events.

```
window.Echo.private('App.User.' + this.data_id)
  .listen('PackageNotification', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
   });
```

and using the [Event Listeners](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/events#generating-events-and-listeners) at laravel documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with Laravel echo. Updating to 1.3.2 fixes it. Check the [issue](https://github.com/laravel/echo/issues/135) on the official repo

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I read about that issue and I tried solve like that but did not work, I solved it for while changing and creating a listen events instead of notification. I still don't know why the way that I was trying using notify it's not pushing out the notifications...

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own and save $.

http://blog.nedex.io/laravel-5-1-broadcasting-events-using-redis-driver-socket-io/

Comment: Thanks for it! I solve for while using a listen Events instead of notification. Almost like that way but using pusher. Your example is using socket.io! Nice tutorial, thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! I wanted to share that with you in case you haven't seen it. I am using the socket.io method for my site over HTTPS and I'm happy.